# Pass same variable to two function using with_items ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to pass the same value to two function. Below is the code

```yaml
- name: Add to servers
  ignore_errors: yes
  uri:
    url: "{{proto}}://{{newserver}}:{{port}}/_reindex"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Authorization: 'Basic ABCDEFGHI=='
    body:
      source :
        remote:
          host: "{{proto}}://{{oldserver}}:{{port}}"
          username: abc
          password: def
        index: "{{item}}" 
        type: "_doc"
      dest:
        index: "{{item}}"
        type: "_doc"
      with_items: "{{jsoncontent.content[6:].splitlines()}}"
    delay: 5
    body_format: json
```

but, its throwing the following error

```
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/somefile/abc.yml: line 72, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem }

...ignoring
```

so my question is, how we can pass the same value of with_items to source and dest         **index: "{{item}}"**. I guess, I am not placing **with_items** to correct indentation. I tried but different indentation but failing.

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved. I created two different yaml file and passed the parameters.

```yaml
- name: remoteFile2
  include_tasks: "file2.yml"
  with_items: "{{jsoncontent.content[6:].splitlines()}}"
```